# MVVM and async tasks with lifetime longer than page's lifetime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, design-patterns, windows-phone-8

MVVM approach is nice and well established. However picture the scene: you have an app page where user can initiate some long-running task. Like synchronization of local and remote databases. This task can be long and should only be interrupted gracefully. Then user leaves the page, by going to some details page. It doesn't make sense to cancel that long async operation, because app is still running. But then suddenly user receives a phone call, so that app is deactivated.

In my (maybe too primitive) understanding of MVVM, View Model should be used to control interactions with the Model (that long operation particularly). But View Model doesn't need to know about application lifetime events, since that will limit code reusability (on Windows 8 there's no such class as PhoneApplicationService). See a contradiction here? VM initiates operation, but should not be used to cancel it.

Of course, View can take this responsibility to handle lifetime events. So that event about app deactivating is propagating like this: `View -> ViewModel -> (cancels long operation) -> Model`. But if user has navigated from the View, and some of operations initiated in that View is still running, there's no way of cancelling it anymore - View can be disposed of at any time.

I've came up with only one idea, that is handling app lifetime events in View Models. But, as I said before, I dislike this approach, because it limits View Models' portability. Could anyone offer a better solution?

Comment: How long of a long running operation are we talking about?  30 seconds, 2 minutes, hours, days?  When you get to a certain point I'd look at using database persistence.  Have `Tasks` that have a completed datetime (that is null if it's running) which you interact with through the view to list/cancel tasks.

Comment: No, it's just matter of seconds. 30 sec is maximum, I'd say. But lots of things can happen on the mobile phone in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've came up with only one idea, that is handling app lifetime events in View Models. But, as I said before, I dislike this approach, because it limits View Models' portability. Could anyone offer a better solution?

I actually do not see a problem here.  In MVVM, the ViewModel is traditionally the "glue" that ties the View to the Model.

Having a small amount of custom ViewModel code for each platform doesn't necessarily limit the portability of the rest of the ViewModel, especially if this is abstracted and contained within its own project for each platform.

> VM initiates operation, but should not be used to cancel it.

This strongly suggests that the VM *should* be the one to cancel it.  If the VM creates these operations, it effectively has ownership of them, which suggests that it should manage their lifecycle, as well.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with this. Although, does that neccesarily mean that the VM should take ownership of the task? It seems like there should be a Model handling long running tasks, and just have the VM indicate to the user somehow that such long running tasks exists (along with options for interaction).

Comment: @sircodesalot It depends on what the task is, really. If the task is application specific, and includes application specific  handling, then I think it's a VM operation.  If it's purely "Model" related and working on the model's data, then it could be in the model.

Comment: I'm even more concerned about adding application lifetime logic into model, than to the view model. For me it looks like app lifetime and data access logic belong to completely different domains and should not be mixed.

Comment: @Haspemulator I do think the VM is the right place for this - the model would be an option, but only if the data and lifecycle was completely controllable from the model, and was very specific to this domain.  That's usually not the case, esp. if it's being generated in response to a view event...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this breaks MVVM principle, but I simply thought like this way.

Regarding the subscription of PhoneApplicationService in VM, are there any reasons not to take this approach like

App -> ViewModel

App is owner of VMs, and if App tells VMs activate/deactivate through interface like view does to its VM, the VM can keep the reusability. but isn't it true once VM subscribe PhoneApplicationService in it, it means VM has dependency on application which means VM and application depends each other and it limits reusability?

About long time task, if it needs to live according to the application lifetime but not to the page lifetime, it can be in App scope as application model or something which can be shared from VMs but not in page(view) scope.

Answer (score 0):

The description you give suggests to me, that there is a missing layer of abstraction.

In particular:

Your ViewModel can of course start long running events that effect the model,
but they do not have any ownership on those long running events. This is exactly
true and should not be broken. If you start a long running event (and your
database synchronisation example is very good here), then the model should
handle this.

The missing part here is in the model I believe. When there are long running
tasks that effect the model, have a separate layer that handles those.
Lets call them `Transaction` for simplicities sake.

So: You start your long running task in the models domain. The model then
executes this task, if it all worked well and it was not interrupted by
some user or system interaction, then the Task Data can be applied to
the model (or the transaction can be committed).

If the user or system cancel the task in some way, no data at all should
be altered in the model. The model itself shall not change!

On the other side, if the model was successfully altered, the ViewModel
should be notified and the view should be updated. But this is only one
of the two main branches of execution you have here. And it is the
one, that is problaby already handled by your MVVM and ViewModel implementation.

Overall:
Your viewmodel shall start and cancel tasks running on the model, but it
does not need to control their lifetime in particular. If you present the 
possibility to cancel the longrunning task, you can fire the cancel event,
but is should gracefully end the task in the model.

Comment: sorry, saw the comments just after sending my answer.

Comment: *user oder system interaction* - let me guess, is German your native language? :)

Comment: Okay, then what about cancellation of those long running `Transactions`? Should they subscribe to app lifetime events and cancel themselves when app deactivates? Or should there be some additional entity which tracks them?

Comment: At the moment I believe that an external object handling those events would be the most appropriate. It hooks into the application events and the long running events can register themselves there. I would not make the Transactions depending on lifecycle themselves. The ViewModel can use the object too, hence the "LifetimeManager" is not part of the ViewModel and not part of the model.